# why does the requests library in python not initialize and function properly

Tags: python, python-requests

I am new to the library of requests. I am trying to import the library requests and was learning from geekforgeeks about the library([https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-requests-tutorial/](https://stackoverflow.com). The following is the code

```
import requests 
print(dir(requests))
```

the following is the output

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\SUCHIISWAR\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\noth.py", line 1, in <module>
    import requests
  File "C:\Users\SUCHIISWAR\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\requests.py", line 4, in <module>
    r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/users/naveenkrnl')
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'requests' has no attribute 'get' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

To fix the problem i referred to this question on stack overflow
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59035409/python-import-requests-results-in-traceback-partially-initialized-module-req](https://stackoverflow.com)

```
  File "C:\Users\SUCHIISWAR\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\noth.py", line 1, in <module>
    import requests
  File "C:\Users\SUCHIISWAR\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\requests.py", line 4, in <module>
    r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/users/naveenkrnl')
```

This part of the error is not even part of the document in which i am writing code but an altogether different .py file in which i was working before the code displayed to you.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCsrq.png)
This is the name of the different .py file i was talking about

I tried referring to the stack overflow question and tried renaming the file. It did not make any difference

Comment: Your file is named `requests.py`, it's overriding the `requests` module. Change your file name to something else and it'll work

Comment: My file is named request.py not requests.py i assume i shouldn't get the error.

Comment: According to the error message you have a file named `requests.py`. And it seems as if you store your files in the Python installation folder. Don't do that.

Comment: i have posted an image for the clarification of the name of the file

Comment: @SuchiiswarPaudmanabhan: The existence of `request.py` does not preclude the existence of `C:\Users\SUCHIISWAR\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\requests.py` *as well*. That file *definitely* exists, and it *definitely* is trying to import the real `requests` module, which fails because it imports itself instead. You clearly have at least three files, named `noth.py`, `requests.py` and `request.py` in that folder (and probably others, since it's in the Python installation folder). Stop putting your new source files in the Python installation itself, and don't name-shadow modules you use.